# Reduce Drupal resource usage

Tags: optimization, drupal-6

I am about to implement a website for a client on his chosen hosting. When I asked, if their hosting was Drupal 6 compatible, they answered that it was, but asked me to make sure, that it is not a hog on resources.

How do I make sure of this?

Are there any resources in particular that would help me optimize the site?

Have You any good suggestions on how to optimize Drupal 6?

P.S.
So far I have found:

- that creating a simple PHP function can reduce 404 time, meanwhile saving resource
- That disabling all of the unneeded modules can really save some resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend reading http://2bits.com/contents/articles — they provide quite a lot of useful information on scaling and optimizing Drupal.

But as a rule of thumb:

- Use page caching
- enable 'optimize CSS files' and 'optimize Javascript files'
- keep the number of used modules to a minimum (and remove any modules that you are not using from the modules directory)

for further improvements

- for anonymous users use advanced caching like [Boost](http://drupal.org/project/boost) if you have largely static content
- if you have lots of registered users, [AuthCache](http://drupal.org/project/authcache) can help.
- use [Pressflow](http://pressflow.org) as a drop-in replacement for Drupal core

However, if your site becomes popular and grows quite a bit, it is more advisable to move to  a VPS or dedicated hardware and look into using Pressflow along with Varnish (you can check http://library.linode.com/application-stacks/project-mercury/ for setup examples)